# extract e-mails from multiple pages in a website and list it

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, python-requests, web-crawler

I would like to extract e-mails of exhibitors from an exhibition website using python. the page contains a hypertext of the exhibitors. when the exhibitor name is clicked you will find the exhibitors profile that includes its e-mail.

You can find the website here:

https://www.medica-tradefair.com/cgi-bin/md_medica/lib/pub/tt.cgi/Exhibitor_index_A-Z.html?oid=80398&lang=2&ticket=g_u_e_s_t

How can I do this using python, please? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please, show us your code, so we could help.

Comment: There are lots of projects that help you crawl the page. You can use selenium for this.

Comment: Questions that do not include code in this context should be closed as too broad. Please add your current coding attempt and research.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab all the links to the exhibitors, then iterate through those and pull the email for each of them:

```
import requests
import bs4


url = 'https://www.medica-tradefair.com/cgi-bin/md_medica/lib/pub/tt.cgi/Exhibitor_index_A-Z.html?oid=80398&lang=2&ticket=g_u_e_s_t'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
exhibitor_links = ['https://www.medica-tradefair.com'+link['href'] for link in links if 'vis/v1/en/exhibitors' in link['href'] ]
exhibitor_links = list(set(exhibitor_links))

for link in exhibitor_links:
    response = requests.get(link)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    name = soup.find('h1',{'itemprop':'name'}).text
    try:
        email = soup.find('a', {'itemprop':'email'}).text
    except:
        email = 'N/A'

    print('Name: %s\tEmail: %s' %(name, email))
```